# Knockout textInput time validation

Tags: javascript, validation, input, knockout.js

Main task:
input text should sent time format "00:00", not "01:1h", or "121:11"

```
<input type="text" data-bind="someInputTimePlugin: value" />
```

May be somebody know any plugins for making something like that, because it should take much time to make this.

Comment: Depending on the target browsers' HTML5 support, using `type="time"` instead of `type="text"` might work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for bad question, nobody leave a good answer!
I find a solution! [jquery Inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask)

html

```
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: element, inputMasked : {'mask': 'hh:mm', 'placeholder': '00:00'}" />
```

js

```
ko.bindingHandlers.inputMasked = {
'init': function (oElement, fValueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var oCommand = _.defaults(
        fValueAccessor(), {
            'mask': 'date',
            'placeholder': '',
        }
    );
    $(oElement).inputmask({
        'alias': oCommand['mask'],
        'placeholder': oCommand['placeholder']
    });
   }
 };
```

May be somebody need it!